# Powershell command works not on c#

Tags: c#, powershell, process.start

I tried to rename a mapped Network Drive with Powershell.
Run the commands in Powershell Script worked it. But when i try with a Powershell Process in c# Comes an Error: Argument cant be NULL.
Have someone any idea whats going wrong with my Code?

```
Process p2 = new Process();
p2.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
p2.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
p2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p2.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p2.StartInfo.Arguments = "$sh=New-Object -com Shell.Application" + " sh.NameSpace('" + webDrive + "').Self.Name = '" + newLabel + "'";   
p2.Start();
string errors = p2.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
MessageBox.Show(errors);
```

Comment: What line is the error on?  It _really_ helps to know that

Comment: Did you try to debug it to make sure that `webDrive` and `newLabel` have the correct values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be (you have forgot $ on sh variable and semicolon between 2 instructions) :

```
p2.StartInfo.Arguments = "$sh=New-Object -com Shell.Application;" + " $sh.NameSpace('" + webDrive + "').Self.Name = '" + newLabel + "'";
```

Comment: You should explain what your answer it doing.  Just pasting some code is of _no_ help to anyone

Comment: Wow, you're right. the semicolon was missing. thanks 1000 times.

Comment: your welcome, have a good time ;)